# Why does the CSS editor not work?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, css, visual-web-developer-2010, css-editor

A few months ago I imported the HTML5/CSS3 update into Visual Web Developer 2010, and after the update ended I could not open CSS files in the Visual Studio editor. When I try I get the error:

```
The operation could not be completed. Unspecified error
```

Here is a image of the error:

[image: error]

I have opened the file successfully in Notepad++, but can be a hassle to do that every time I need to edit CSS or want to debug and switch windows.
Why is this happening? What can I do about it? Is my CSS editor broken for good?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out since I had installed the [Web Standards Update for Visual Studio 2010 S1](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/a15c3ce9-f58f-42b7-8668-53f6cdc2cd83), it didn't work. All I had to do was open the installer again and repair the update. I can now open .css files again!

**EDIT**

Useful link I used: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/vssetup/thread/e505875a-0b74-4d46-987b-e376f958b9bc